# How to read/write server-side from html

Tags: javascript, html, server-side

I'm trying to make a sign-up form. I don't know much about JavaScript or any other server-side languages but, I'm wondering if its possible to store user's data, in a text file and have a password and login prefix, and be able to read that file and output it somewhere else.

I have looked into: Cookies, and DOM. But I don't want the user to logout and not be able to sign back in. What would be the best way to read/write from a script onto a .txt file?

It would look something like this:

```
username: abc
password: 123
```

and output:

```
usrnm: (first line)
pswrd: (second line)
```

and maybe be able to see if the text has stopped with a comma, and be able to go onto the next line, and read, write. etc.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read about [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). Right now your question is very broad and is unlikely to get a good answer. For example, you haven't specified what type of server you want to use.

Comment: @Jason Aller whats a good server script should i use?

Comment: That is going to depend on what you have available to you, and what it is you are trying to build. Rather than trying to make your own login system, many frameworks out there already have well put together user management systems. If you are trying to build your own in order to learn, pick a language and learn that first.

Comment: you're better off attending a course altogether. Login details would normally be stored on a database in the firstplace.